# Do i need to create nested struct always for fetching just one property from nested model in json response?

Tags: ios, json, swift

assume use of JSONDecoder for this question.

Do i need to create nested struct always for fetching just one property from nested model in json response?

for eg consider below json response:
i saw few tutorials where they were creating structure to fetch nested property (like company name from below example), my question is what if i need only userid, user name and company name
from below response. Do i still need to create separate struct for company. and then access name property inside it.

```
like ...
struct user{
     id : Int
     name : String?
     company : Company?
}
struct Company{
     name : String?
}
```

can't it possible with only one structure ? why to create one more structure just to fetch one property ?

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Leanne Graham",
    "username": "Bret",
    "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
    "address": {
      "street": "Kulas Light",
      "suite": "Apt. 556",
      "city": "Gwenborough",
      "zipcode": "92998-3874",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-37.3159",
        "lng": "81.1496"
      }
    },
    "phone": "1-770-736-8031 x56442",
    "website": "hildegard.org",
    "company": {
      "name": "Romaguera-Crona",
      "catchPhrase": "Multi-layered client-server neural-net",
      "bs": "harness real-time e-markets"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Ervin Howell",
    "username": "Antonette",
    "email": "Shanna@melissa.tv",
    "address": {
      "street": "Victor Plains",
      "suite": "Suite 879",
      "city": "Wisokyburgh",
      "zipcode": "90566-7771",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-43.9509",
        "lng": "-34.4618"
      }
    },
    "phone": "010-692-6593 x09125",
    "website": "anastasia.net",
    "company": {
      "name": "Deckow-Crist",
      "catchPhrase": "Proactive didactic contingency",
      "bs": "synergize scalable supply-chains"
    }
  }
]
```

is this possible to write  ?

```
struct user{
     id : Int
     name : String?
     companyname : String?

        private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case name
        case companyname = "company.name"
    }
}
```

Comment: `Company` looks like a useful abstraction. Perhaps today it only has a name, but in the future it might have a stock ticker name, a number of employees, etc. I would keep it.

Answer (score 3):

You don't *have* to create nested structs; you could create one struct with a custom `init(from:)` method that dumpster-dives into the JSON by hand. The reason for using multiple structs is that you don't have to write the `init(from:)` method. Pick one approach or the other, whichever suits your overall needs.

Comment: struct user{
     id : Int
     name : String?
     company.name : String?
} .    is this possible ?

Comment: @Matrix Certainly, if (as I said) you write your own `init(from:)` to dumpster-dive into the JSON and initialize those properties. For people who like to do that kind of thing, that is the kind of thing they like to do. But you cannot call a property `company.name`; that's illegal in Swift.

Answer (score 1):

There are two basic approaches:

1. Using custom coding where necessary. See [Encoding and Decoding Custom Types: Encode and Decode Manually](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types).

   I don’t see levels that need to be collapsed, here, as they all seem relevant and useful abstractions. That having been said, the structure of the geocoding data in the address seems suboptimal, namely `latitude` and `longitude` shouldn’t be strings and we should avoid cryptic names like `geo` and `lng`. So I might do something like:

   ```
   struct Address: Codable {
       let street: String?
       let suite: String?
       let city: String?
       let zipcode: String?
       let coordinate: Coordinate?

       enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
           case street, suite, city, zipcode
           case coordinate = "geo"
       }
   }

   struct Coordinate: Codable {
       var latitude: Double
       var longitude: Double

       enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
           case latitude = "lat"
           case longitude = "lng"
       }

       init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
           let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

           guard let latitude = try Double(values.decode(String.self, forKey: .latitude)) else {
               throw DecodingError.dataCorruptedError(forKey: .latitude, in: values, debugDescription: "Latitude not valid string")
           }

           guard let longitude = try Double(values.decode(String.self, forKey: .longitude)) else {
               throw DecodingError.dataCorruptedError(forKey: .longitude, in: values, debugDescription: "Longitude not valid string")
           }

           self.latitude = latitude
           self.longitude = longitude
       }

       func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
           var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
           try container.encode(String(latitude), forKey: .latitude)
           try container.encode(String(longitude), forKey: .longitude)
       }
   }
   ```

   I might even add a computed property to return a `CLLocationCoordinate2D` I the `Coordinate` type.

   But the idea is that we should use best practice structures on the client side, and do isolated custom encoding and decoding where necessary.
2. But, you suggest you don’t like the idea of having a `company` property in `Users` of type `Company` and that you’d like to flatten that structure. Personally, I wouldn’t suggest flattening it (because if you later decide you need all of these company properties, do you really want the `User` object to have `companyName`, `companyCatchPhrase` and `companyBs` properties). The idea of a distinct `Company` entity is probably prudent, IMHO.

   But let’s set this aside, and assume you did want to flatten this structure. You theoretically could use this custom [`init(from:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/decodable/2894081-init) approach and write cumbersome initializers to collapse levels from your JSON. But that would lead to pretty ugly code. (It would yield code that [matt aptly calls “dumpster diving”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58682656/1271826). The more properties you have, the uglier it gets.)

   Apple’s suggestion in this case is to create a “service” structure that mirrors the JSON structure, and then, write a custom initializer for your actual model objects that take these service objects. See the “Access Nested Data” section of [Using JSON with Custom Types](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/using_json_with_custom_types). Anyway, that would look like:

   ```
   struct UserService: Codable {
       let id: Int
       let name: String?
       let company: Company?

       struct Company: Codable {
           let name: String?
       }
   }

   struct User {
       let id: Int
       let name: String?
       let companyName: String?

       init(from service: UserService) {
           id = service.id
           name = service.name
           companyName = service.company?.name
       }
   }
   ```

   Then you can do:

   ```
   do {
       let users = try JSONDecoder()
           .decode([UserService].self, from: data)
           .map { User(from: $0) }
   } catch {
       print(error)
   }
   ```

   Again, I wouldn’t necessarily recommend that approach here, but if you did, that’s one reasonably simple way of doing it. You end up with one clean structure reflecting the API format and another that reflects your app’s actual model objects, but without the ugly, manual decoding code.